# Simple button click - Show content issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably going to be a very simple mistake, but I've spent the last hour on it and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

What I'm trying to do is build a testimonials section, where a user will:

- Click a company logo
- If there is an existing testimonial active,    remove it
- Load the selected testimonial below

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rv9HF/

```
$('.logobuttons a').click(function() {
   var link = $(this).attr('class');

   $('.testimonial-content blockquote').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).fadeOut(300);
        }
   });

   $('testimonial-content ' + link).fadeIn(300);
});



<section id="testimonials">
   <div class="logobuttons">
       <a class="tc-1" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
       <a class="tc-2" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
       <a class="tc-2" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
       <a class="tc-2" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="testimonial-content">
       <blockquote class="tc-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </blockquote>
       <blockquote class="tc-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </blockquote>
       <blockquote class="tc-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </blockquote>
       <blockquote class="tc-4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
       </blockquote>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have many typos and need to prevent the anchor default behavior on click http://jsfiddle.net/N2EZh/

Comment: Or even simpler, use data attribute to specify the target selector, which is more flexible; http://jsfiddle.net/VfT6p/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing two periods in your Sizzle selector, this should work.

```
    $('.logobuttons a').click(function(e) {
        var link = $(this).attr('class');

        $('.testimonial-content blockquote').each(function() {
             if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                 $(this).fadeOut(300);
             }
        });

      $('.testimonial-content .' + link).fadeIn(300);

       e.preventDefault();
   });
```

Comment: This.  I also suggest the href's in each <a> to have a value of #